# can't copy file to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I try to copy a file from my local to S3 bucket using AWS - CLI.
this is my command:

```
aws s3 cp /path/to/local/file s3://bucket-name
```

but the message I get is :

```
An error occured (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

I've set the policy in my s3 bucket to accept everything, like this:

```
{
    "Id": "BucketPolicy",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllAccess",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*"
            ],
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What could be the reason I'm getting this error?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

- Worth checking your command, For copy, you need to specify the source file. The destination file can be current directory.[aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)

```
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt
```

- Basic bucket policy [aws s3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-bucket-policy.html)
- This policy allows all users to retrieve any object in MyBucket. It also grants put and delete permission to the **root** user of the AWS account 1234-5678-9012.

```
{
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Action": "s3:GetObject",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*"
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
         ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*"
      }
   ]
}
```